# Functor class using member variable

Tags: c++, functor

```
struct test
{
  bool operator()(const test &lhs, const test &rhs)
  {
    if(flag)
    {
      // do stuff
    }
  }

  bool flag;
};

std::priority_queue<test, std::vector<test>, test> pq;
```

In this functor class here (constructed for the purpose of being a custom comparator for the prior, it uses a flag variable, but it's not clear to me which object's flag variable it is using. Is the behavior undefined here?

Comment: Does the class have a constructor which initializes the flag? If so, it's well defined.

Comment: If this is all then no, `flag` will be uninitialized.

Comment: The `priority_queue` will create its own default-constructed instance of the specified comparator, unless you pass an instance to the `priority_queue`'s constructor. But your `test` struct is not doing anything to initialize its own `flag` member, so the behavior will be undefined as the `flag` value is indeterminate.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` has a member variable of the comparator type.  It is that object that is used by the `std::priority_queue` object.

Comment: @interjay No, in this case there's no default initialization. There's a custom initializer that's called when putting a `test` object inside the `pq` (but I don't think that affects the `flag` variable here since it's not attributed to the object emplaced into the `pq`?)

Comment: @NathanOliver So if I were to use `std::priority_queue::emplace(some_test_object)`, it will use the `some_test_object`'s flag? I think `some_test_object` is just `lhs` here if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @roulette01 The priority queue generates one `test` object when constructed to use as a comparator. It doesn't really make sense to use the same class as both the value type and the comparison as you do here.

Comment: @roulette01 No, inside `std::priority_queue` there is going to be a class member like `Compare comp;`.  It is that object that will be used when any comparison is needed.

Comment: @interjay Ah you're right. I usually don't do this. But if you have a custom comparator that's only used for that particular class, doesn't it make sense to define the functor within that class as well, or is it better practice to define it outside of the class?

Comment: @roulette01: Outside of the class, unless it's `operator<`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is undefined. This line of code:

```
std::priority_queue<test, std::vector<test>, test> pq;
```

Is equivalent to

```
std::priority_queue<test, std::vector<test>, test> pq{test()};
```

You can instead pass your own instance of `test`:

```
std::priority_queue<test, std::vector<test>, test> pq{test{false}};
```

Answer (score -1):

`flag` is undefined in your case. Moreover, the declaration of `bool flag` in the struct is having no effect as it is **out of scope.**

Comment: How is it out of scope?

Comment: The scope of your function is different then the scope of your struct. Once the scope of your function ends, anything initialized even in the struct makes no difference to your function.